# how to find a string before another string

Tags: php, string, search

i have a string for example :

```
"{{foo-1 456}}{{foo-2 abc}} {{foo-3 ghi}}{{foo-4 456}}{{foo-5 abc}}{{foo-6ghi}}"
              **                                      **
              find this position (1st)                not this position (2nd)
```

i need to find the position of the `{{` before the `foo` (in this case `foo-2`) that is in front of the first `abc`

`foo` is always unknown in content and lenght and `foo` can be different everytime, but i know its between the a `{{` and `abc` and then extract it from the string by finding the first `}}` from that position.

the result should be

```
"foo-2 abc"
```

i can acomplish this by doing alot of seperated searches, but it slows down my script alot as these strings can get quite big in size.

is there a way i can search backwards from the first `abc` ?

this is what i use now; it is working but gets to big.

```
//$Temp is found by the parameter $item in another routine. 
//but $Temp can change so its never the same.
//i just put it here like this so i dont have to put all the code.

$Temp = "__NOTOC__== Weak Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Weak Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Weak Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment(30 m): +3% damage vs. centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills| type = consumable| level = 5| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Weak Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 5| mat-1 = Jug of Water| amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Rawhide Leather Scrap| amt-2 =1| mat-3 = Carrot| amt-3 =1| mat-4 = Pile of Glittering Dust| amt-4 =1| discipline = Artificer| level = 25}}{{clear}}== Minor Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Minor Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Minor Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment(30 m): +5% damage vs. centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills| type = consumable| level = 20| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Minor Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 5| mat-1 = Jug of Water| amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Thin Leather Section | amt-2 =1| mat-3 = Carrot| amt-3 =1| mat-4 = Pile of Shimmering Dust| amt-4 =1| discipline = Artificer| level = 100}}{{clear}}== Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment (30 m): 7% damage vs centaur<BR>-4% damage from centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills| type = consumable| level = 35| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 5| mat-1 = Jug of Water | amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Coarse Leather Section| amt-2 =1| mat-3 = Carrot| amt-3 =1| mat-4 = Pile of Radiant Dust| amt-4 =1| discipline = Artificer| level = 175}}{{clear}}== Strong Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Strong Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Strong Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment (30 m): 8% damage vs centaur<BR>-6% damage from centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills | type = consumable| level = 50| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Strong Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 5| mat-1 = Jug of Water| amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Rugged Leather Section | amt-2 = 3 Carrot| amt-3 = 1| mat-4 = Pie of Luminous Dust| amt-4 = 1| discipline = Artificer| level = 250}}{{clear}}== Potent Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Potent Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Potent Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment (30 m): 9% damage vs centaur<BR>-7% damage from centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills | type = consumable| level = 65| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Potent Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 5| mat-1 = Jug of Water| amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Thick Leather Section| amt-2 =1| mat-3 = Carrot| amt-3 =1| mat-4 = Pile of Incandescent Dust| amt-4 =1| discipline = Artificer| level = 325}}{{clear}}== Powerful Potion of Centaur Slaying =={{Item infobox| name = Powerful Potion of Centaur Slaying| icon = Powerful Potion of Centaur Slaying.png| rarity = basic| description = Nourishment (1 h): 10% damage vs centaur<BR>-10% damage from centaur<BR>+10 Experience from kills | type = consumable| level = 80| value = 2}}{{Recipe| name = Powerful Potion of Centaur Slaying| quantity = 10| mat-1 = Jug of Water | amt-1 =1| mat-2 = Hardened Leather Section | amt-2 =1| mat-3 = Carrot| amt-3 =1| mat-4 = Pile of Crystalline Dust| amt-4 =1 | discipline = Artificer| level = 400}}{{clear}}== Notes ==*== Trivia ==*== Bugs ==* Currently, entering the recipe for the Powerful variant of the potion in the discovery pane twice will discover the recipe for the Extended variant of the potion. These potions are identical to Powerful potions, only of Rare quality, soulbound, and worth 1c";
$Item = "Minor Potion of Centaur Slaying";

// start : is there an item infobox this time? (for the specific item)
if(stristr($Temp, '{{Item infobox |') !== FALSE)
{
    // check to see if its the one i want
    do
    {
        $Item_infobox = substr($Temp, strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") + 2, strpos($Temp, "}}",strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") + 2) - strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") - 2);
        $Temp = str_replace("{{" . $Item_infobox . "}}", "", $Temp);
        if(stristr($Item_infobox, '| name = ' . $Item) !== FALSE)
        {
            // found it
            echo $Item_infobox . "<br/><br/>";  
            break;  
        }
    } 
    while (stristr($Temp, '{{Item infobox |') !== FALSE);
}
// stop : is it an item infobox this time? (for the specific item)


// start : is there an crafting infobox this time? (for the specific item)
if(stristr($Temp, '{{Crafting infobox |') !== FALSE)
{
    // check to see if its the one i want
    do
    {
        $Crafting_infobox = substr($Temp, strpos($Temp, "{{Crafting infobox |") + 2, strpos($Temp, "}}",strpos($Temp, "{{Crafting infobox |") + 2) - strpos($Temp, "{{Crafting infobox |") - 2);
        $Temp = str_replace("{{" . $Crafting_infobox . "}}", "", $Temp);
        if(stristr($Crafting_infobox, '| name = ' . $Item) !== FALSE)
        {
            // found it
            echo $Crafting_infobox . "<br/><br/>";  
            break;  
        }
    } 
    while (stristr($Temp, '{{Crafting infobox |') !== FALSE);
}
// stop : is it an crafting infobox this time? (for the specific item)

// repeat this routine for every different infobox (around 50) until i find the correct one.
```

here are some other example $Temp and $Item that belong together.
again. i have to get $temp every time according to $item as $temp i bound to change over time. this is just to show how diverse the string can be.

```
//exammple 2
$Temp = "{{stub}}{{Crafting infobox| name = Gift of Color| type = legendary| description = A gift of color used to create [[The Bifrost]].| rarity = legendary }}==Acquisition==A [[Gift of Color]] can be crafted by a level 400 [[Cook]]. The required [[Recipe: Gift of Color]] can be bought from [[Miyani]] at the [[Mystic Forge]].{{Recipe | name = Gift of Color| mat-1 = Pile of Crystalline Dust| amt-1 = 250| mat-2 = Opal Orb| amt-2 = 100| mat-3 = Gift of Zhaitan| amt-3 = 1| mat-4 = Unidentified Dye| amt-4 = 250|discipline=Chef|level=400|exp}}";
$Item = "Gift of Color";

//exammple 3
$Temp = "{{Inventory infobox| name = 20 Slot Safe Box| slots= 20| property =| description = 20 Slots, Items in this box will never appear in a sell-to-vendor list and will not move when inventory is sorted.| rarity = fine| type = box| value = 54}}{{clear}}== Recipes  =={{Recipe| name = 20 Slot Safe Box| mat-1 = Orichalcum Ingot| amt-1 = 10| mat-2 = Superior Rune of Holding| amt-2 = 1| mat-3 = Pile of Crystalline Dust| amt-3 = 3| discipline = Armorsmith| level = 400}}==See also==*[[20 Slot Invisible Bag]]*[[20 Slot Invisible Leather Pack]][[Category:Armorsmith recipes]]";
$Item = "20 Slot Safe Box";
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: $Item_infobox = substr($Temp, strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") + 2, strpos($Temp, "}}",strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") + 2) - strpos($Temp, "{{Item infobox |") - 2); change 'item'  to 50 diferent types. i want to determen that afterwards. right now i'm perfoming 50 searches on the string.

Comment: There is no `'Item infobox |'` anywhere in the text that you have supplied us. Give us your input and expected output and merge this comment into your question.

Comment: @LoneWolf It would be nice for you to edit your code into your question so others can see what's wrong.

Comment: i will edit and add the code after i get back from work. i will also provide some exmaple strings that i have to work with.

Comment: combination of `strpos()`, `substr()`, `explode()` will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace within substr. I think this will help.